# Finding all closed figures using OpenCv in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I want to find all the closed shapes in the image with sampled points using opencv in python. I got all the contours using cv2.findContours() method and sampled it using cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE. Now if two closed figures share the same boundary, I am unable to segregate them as shown in the figure. The contour is shown in the image below.
[image]

The outer rectangle and the border share the same boundary. So the contour is not giving all the closed figure in such cases. The original figure is shown below:
[image]

The code that I am using is :

`im2,contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(imagem,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 count=(len(contours))`

Please suggest me modifications or some other methods to find out all the closed images in python opencv.

Comment: modifications to what? you did not even provide all your parameters to findContours()... if you want help on your code, post your code. please read [ask]

Comment: Added. Just check.

Comment: Hi there, Did you find  any solution? Can you atleast post your code here?